# Sessions and parallel deployment in Tomcat 7

Tags: session, tomcat, tomcat7

Concerning parallel deployment, the [Tomcat 7 configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) says:

> You may deploy multiple versions of a web application with the same context path at the same time. The rules used to match requests to a context version are as follows:
>
> - If no session information is present in the request, use the latest version.
> - If session information is present in the request, check the session manager of each version for a matching session and if one is found, use that version.
> - If session information is present in the request but no matching session can be found, use the latest version.

My question is severalfold:

1. What exactly is meant by, "If no session information is present in the request"? Is this just looking for a `jsessionid` cookie in the request (or in the URL or wherever it's configured to be)?
2. In what unit should I be looking for where the request is matched to a context? I've been poring over the Tomcat 7.0 source, but I am not able to see where this happens.
3. Is there a way to lie to Tomcat about there being session information present? I am already lying to Tomcat by setting the `requestedSessionId` of the request to the contents of the `X-Auth-Token` header in a valve, but I suspect this happens too late to fool whatever decides to send the request to the new version.
4. In the event that there's no way to lie to Tomcat, would a custom session manager be a viable solution to the problem? It doesn't seem so to me, because it seems like the yes-or-no question of whether there is session information in the request is answered without consulting the session manager.

Comment: The answers to the first two were right in from of me. The matching is happening in `CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest()`, and it uses the configured method for locating a session ID. Sadly, `postParseRequest()` happens just before valves are invoked, so this can't be used to inject a session ID into the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you store session into memcached and set sticky to false, Tomcat WILL not handle session by itself, but read session from memcached every time when necessary.

Thus Tomcat will undeploy old version as new version is ready without checking session, because Tomcat doesn't handle session.

It is a very useful feature for us. We don't need use rolling upgrade and change load balancer when we have to deploy new version.